# Line Chart as Ladder react-chartjs-2 with xAxis and yAxis as labels groups and weeks number over lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, linechart, react-chartjs-2

I try to add such line chart with categories on yAxis and time duration on xAxis and labels over lines. I chose for this purpose Line Chart and right now try to play with different options, but currently haven't found correct settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7foio.png)
Main issue is that on xAxis and yAxis aren't numbers but labels and also need duration in weeks for each category.

Current settings

```
`const settings = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function () {
          return null;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  interaction: {
    mode: "nearest" as const,
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
    },
  },
};`
```

In datasets I put currently numbers:

```
`const data = {
        borderColor: COLORS.BLACK,
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Group 1",
            borderColor: COLORS.BLACK,
            data: [
              [1, 1],
              [2, 1],
            ],
          },
          {
            label: "Group 2",
            data: [
              [2, 2],
              [3, 2],
            ],
          }]
};`
```

So currently lines are shown as ladder but still haven't found how to configure it to show as in picture.